# AngularJS files upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

I am new to Angularjs, now I need to create a files upload for my api, the requirement is after I upload my files ( it will mostly like be img), user will be able to view the img which was uploaded to server. I searched some upload solution online, most of them are pre-view, but I also need after-view.There is a default img for upload icon, but after you click it and upload files successfully, I need to use file's img to replace default img for upload icon.
Any one can give me a sample?

Comment: I use, and am a big fan of, [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload).  You can store the url that the file is uploaded to and update a $scope.variable to that url on successful upload. If that sounds like something you would want to use I can post some code examples as an answer below

Comment: so, you mean after I successfully upload my files to server, the server will send back the url of my files in callback function, and I can use this as src for my upload icon background-img?

Comment: You should know what URL you are uploading the files to, if you were, for example, using PHP for the actual upload of the file you might have something like `move_upload_file($_FILES["file"]["temp_file"], '../img/upload' . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);` The $_FILES variable was passed through via angular, so you should have access to that, so you can set the source of your image to `/img/upload/FILE_NAME`

Comment: yah, of course,I will know server URL for files upload, in my case  the point is after I upload the files, there will return a json data in success function, that will include the url of img which I upload, what I am going to do is change the default upload icon img src to this src? I hope I already understood. Would you please show me some code which can makes me understand better? Thanks!

Comment: Here is my sample code: <td class="text-center"><div class="uploadbox" <img src="files.src"/><input type="file" accept="image/*" image="image" style="filter: alpha(opacity=0);opacity: 0;width:35px;height:35px;">
         </div></td>

Comment: Yeah I won't have time to sit down and do it until later, I apologize but ill get it up soon

Comment: Good plugin for image-upload: [link](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)
You can attach on the finished load event and get your new URL and set this one down to the image-src you want to.

Comment: Hi Jacob, Thanks a lot if you can provide me a sample code :)